# Customizing SimpleMembership Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I am using simple membership provider in mvc4 application and I can see five tables generated for that. In that i can see username and password are stored on different tables. I want to save username and password on the same table with some custom fields. So I am creating my own Membership Provider by inheriting ExtendingMembership Provider. I have some queries over that.

1. My application uses 3-tier architecture(BLL, DAL and Presentation layers) and created 2 areas for account and admin. So here i dont know where to  place my membership provider which are then accessed with every part of application for using Authorize Attribute.
2. I am overriding this method CreateUserAndAccount, Do i need to implement my own logic for saving user registration datas to database. But i find only some parameters are passed, how to pass my remaining custom fields from view to the controller using the dictionary object ?

   ```
   public override string CreateUserAndAccount(string userName, string password, bool     requireConfirmation, IDictionary<string, object> values)
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for question #2: Check out this question I asked this weekend... [SimpleMemership CreateUserAndAccount Customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542257/simplememership-createuserandaccount-customization) - specifically the blog post I linked in the question as it's very helpful about extending SimpleMembership.

Answer (score 0):

For #1: Use DI to inject `ExtendedMembershipProvider` into your BLL layer as required. Map it in your DI configuration to Membership.Provider. This is effectively a DAL and should not contain business logic. Better still create a facade around WebSecurity and inject that into your BLL instead.

For #2: Yes the `ExtendedMembershipProvider` interface uses a dictionary of Key/Value pairs which can be used to map user profile properties to the database schema using an implementation of your choosing.

`SimpleMembershipProvider` does this by mapping the dictionary keys to corresponding database columns. Once the record has been created, you can then manage the user data using EF and the `UserProfile` model directly.

Implementing your own `ExtendedMembershipProvider` is a lot of work and I wouldn't recommend it. The `SimpleMembershipProvider` schema is relatively clean compared to legacy iterations, and I think you would need a very good reason for wanting to move password column to the user table, rather than just configuring `SimpleMembershipProvider` to use your own schema, and leaving password where it rightly belongs.